# Displaying JSON Object in UITableView Cell - App Crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm loading a json file from my server which have several fields like id,category,value,price.i tried SBJSON library files. If i'm trying to display single content in a cell i'm using the following code

```
cell.textLabel.text=[[mutarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"id"];
```

but if i need to display all the field like id,category,value in each cell.i'm not aware of that.Kindly guide me..

here mutarray is my NSMutableArray which contains all elements of my json file..

Comment: can you give us the format of the json, please

Comment: [{"id":"1","category":"KIDS WEAR","title":"anandi01","description":"exclusive kids saree \/ ready pleated sarees with ready made blouse for kids?","spectitle":"Price: S$","specvalue":"44.00"},{"id":"3","category":"KIDS WEAR","title":"FULWA 01","description":"exclusive kids saree \/ ready pleated sarees with ready made blouse for kids?","spectitle":"Price: S$","specvalue":"39.00"}]

Comment: you should use any `CustomCellView` if you want to show more details of your datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i done that using following code

```
cell.textlabel.text=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[mutarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"id"]];
```

The issue is i forgot to convert the JSON Object into NSSTring

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put custom cells. Please check the link below and tell me if any doubts.

[Putting Custom Cells in Table View](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/)